# phonegap server communication problem

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I know that phonegap does not provide any server communication functionality, I would like to ask any open source framework can do that?If I used jquery-mobile,I won't use phonegap function. because AJAX doesn't work when using phonegap.

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect: Phonegap is perfectly able to make ajax requests.

Comment: @Ben Poole, could you link to the corresponding documentation?

Comment: No. My comment addressed the assertion that "AJAX doesn't work when using phonegap", which is not true. Developers are free to include such calls using their code / framework of choice, and there's nothing in PhoneGap to prevent that. So I'm not sure what documentation you would need to see?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery JS file along with jquery-mobile and phonegap . this will let you make AJAX calls